# Is there a way to get the absolute position of a Button through appium in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I am currently trying to use appium to find the position of various elements an an android app.

I have tried:

```
driver.elementByName('button1').location;
driver.elementByName('button1').getLocationOnScreen();
driver.elementByName('button1').getAttribute('location');
```

but none of these seem to work. I have also tried to find some helpful documentation but nothing seems to be relevant to this problem. I know you can use:

```
driver.elementByName('button1').Text();
```

To find the text of an element but I can't find any resources on what other commands there are. If anyone can help or even just point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to first find the button as a separate webelement

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("button's path or id "))
```

then print the location as

```
System.out.printf("Location is ", +button.getLocationOnScreen());
```

I guess there wont be much difference in using the functions in java and javascript.